# Mstest Run ignored tests in VS

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, tfs, mstest

I have created a number of long running integration tests.  They take around 5-10 minutes to complete.  I don't want them to run Everytime the developers run tests from VS as it will take a long time. They are purely ad hoc tests

Is there a way to mark a test as ignored but still allow developers to run it locally if they explicitly select and run the test without removing ignore tag each time?  Also i want these tests to run during overnight build via TFS and MS test runner

Comment: What version of TFS are you using? Are you using the new build system or the old XAML build system?

Comment: Im using tfs 2015

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you look into using [Test Categories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286683.aspx).

By categorising your long running tests separately, you can choose what to include on test runs, e.g.

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("Integration")]  
public void MyLongRunningTest()  
{  
    // Test Code
}
```

And to run:

```
mstest /testcontainer:TestProject.dll /category:"Integration"
```

Comment: If i run all solution tests on vs,  will this test still run?

Comment: Yes, or you can group the tests by TestCategoryAttribute and then choose to only run the test groups you want. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270865.aspx

Comment: I want to not run these tests unless a developer explicitly wants to run it.  Hope it makes sense

Comment: Then just get the developers into the habit of running a test group that has been setup which excludes integration tests instead of "Run All". Run All means Run All!

Comment: Except ones that are ignored or disabled